# Export a BLOB image from table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, blob, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have table in Oracle 11G R2, named as PERSON_IMAGE with ID (Number) and IMAGE(BLOB) fields. Now without using the application i need to export multiple BLOBs. 
How can i do this? Do we have any tool/ utility for this? 
Example will really assist me.

Comment: Export to where - the server or the client machine? If the client PC, which client application are you actually using - SQL Developer and PL/SQL developer are different tools. As a single extract (i.e. a real export, with expdp) or one image file per user? A one-off task or something you'll do regularly?

Comment: @AlexPoole Its a one-off task and i intend downloading the BLOBs using client machine which has sql developer with it.

Comment: I don't think you can do that on the client machine with SQL Developer. You can use expdp or utl_file to write the BLOBs out, but on the server, not the client. [This is the closest question I can see](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13531576/266304) but that is about exporting to a text file. I don't know if the tool that refers to, SQL Workbench/J, can export BLOBs as standalone binary files.

Comment: @AlexPoole: yes, SQL Workbench can export BLOB columns as standalone files: http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-export.html#export-example-lobs

Answer (score 3):

SQLDeveloper can do it:

http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/05/exporting-multiple-blobs-with-oracle-sql-developer/

I just tried it in version 4.0.3 and although the interface was a little unintuitive, it worked fine. I ended up with a lot of files called `TABLE64c49834-014d-1000-8494-c0a8b247f35d.ldr` rather than `david.jpg` but it should be relatively straightforward to process the loader data file with a shell script if you want to rename them.