# Oracle - extract images from BLOB

Tags: oracle, image, blob, extract

I'm really green. I want to extract images (JPGs) from Oracle PDB. Table Looks something like this:

```
select * from BOB.USER_ID t


    LINK_ID     ID_SCAN
1  340101001    <BLOB>...
2  340101002    <BLOB>...
3  340101003    <BLOB>...
4  340101004    <BLOB>...
5  ...
```

If possible, I want to extract them, with LINK_ID names (340101001.jpg).

I can extract them one-by-one, but there are ~5000 images... I would love to do it with some command or something...

I've looked for solution, but things that I could understand a little, they didn't work.

Thank you and sorry for inconvenience.

---

I tried to do "cart" method,? but it didn't work out. I couldn't open files that were extracted. I also tried third-party software, OraLobEditor.
Other then that, I could not understand codes and commands, I found in internet.
I'm trying to use SQL and PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: Post what you tried, what didn't you understand, what were the errors? Have you got code with a connection string to the dB? I think this is better asked at DBA.stackexchange.com you haven't even listed a programming language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export a BLOB image from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271767/export-a-blob-image-from-table)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a package that has a bunch of file utilities that all work with Oracle DIRECTORY objects and the files within them. With this and some PL/SQL, you could easily extract BLOB's to files at the OS level. The procedure you're going to want to work with is blob_into_file. But you need to start by creating an Oracle directory object, which points to the location on the OS that you want to save the files. Note that the directory needs to be writable by the same OS user that the database is running as.

Example, where MY_IMAGES is the Oracle directory object, and '/tmp/my_images' is the directory on the filesystem, wriable by the user running the database - "oracle", for example.

```
Create or replace directory MY_IMAGES as '/tmp/my_images';
Grant read, write on directory MY_IMAGES to BOB;
```

Next, a simple loop that will write the objects to the OS ***after*** you've compiled the fileutils package provided below. This can be run via SQL*Plus or SQL-Developer.

```
--
-- This is the code that does the export of the images
--    

Set serveroutput on;

Begin

   For i in (Select link_id, id_scan from bob.user_id) loop

      dbms_output.put_line('Exporting image '||i.link_id||'.jpg');
      fileutils.blob_into_file('MY_IMAGES',i.link_id||'.jpg',i.id_scan);

   End loop;

End;
/
```

Package spec

```
Create or replace package fileutils as

   --
   -- This procedure deletes a file, and depends on an Oracle DIRECTORY object being passed
   --
   Procedure delete_os_file (i_directory varchar2, i_filename varchar2);

   --
   -- This procedure moves and optionally renames a file, 
   -- and depends on an Oracle DIRECTORY object being passed
   --
   Procedure move_os_file ( i_source_directory in varchar2, i_source_file in varchar2, i_target_directory in varchar2, i_target_file in varchar2);

   --
   -- This procedure takes a blob variable and writes it to a file, 
   -- and depends on an Oracle DIRECTORY object being passed
   --
   Procedure blob_into_file (i_directory in varchar2, i_file_name in varchar2, i_blob in blob);

   --
   -- This procedure takes a file and uploads it into a blob variable
   -- and depends on an Oracle DIRECTORY object being passed
   --
   Procedure file_into_blob(i_directory in varchar2, i_file_name in varchar2, o_blob out blob);

   --
   -- This procedure converts a clob to a blob
   --
   Procedure convert_clob_to_blob (i_clob in clob, o_blob out blob);

   --
   -- This procedure converts a blob to a clob
   --
   Procedure convert_blob_to_clob (i_blob in blob, o_clob out clob);

   --
   -- This one checks for file existence without Java
   --
   Function file_exists (i_directory in varchar2, i_filename in varchar2) return boolean;

   --
   -- Returns the basename of a filename
   -- Works with Windows and UNIX pathnames
   --
   Function basename (i_filename in varchar2) return varchar2;

   --
   -- This takes a Base64 string and converts it to a binary BLOB
   --
   Procedure base64_string_to_blob (i_clob in clob, o_blob out blob);
   Function base64_string_to_blob (i_clob in clob) return blob;

   --
   -- This takes a binary BLOB and converts it to a Base64 string
   --
   Procedure blob_to_base64_string (i_blob in blob, o_clob out clob);
   Function blob_to_base64_string (i_blob in blob) return clob;

End fileutils;
/

Show error;
```

Package body

```
Set define off;

Create or replace package body fileutils as

   Procedure delete_os_file (i_directory varchar2, i_filename varchar2)
   is

   Begin

      utl_file.fremove(i_directory,i_filename);

   End;

   Procedure move_os_file
   (
      i_source_directory     in varchar2,
      i_source_file          in varchar2,
      i_target_directory     in varchar2,
      i_target_file          in varchar2
   )

   is

      srcdir               varchar2(255) := upper(i_source_directory);
      tgtdir               varchar2(255) := upper(i_target_directory);

   begin

      --
      -- NOTE: If you're getting the all-too-familiar
      -- ORA-29292: file rename operation failed
      -- and you're SURE that your directory names are correct,
      -- and you're SURE that your privileges are correct, both at the
      -- OS level, and within the database, there's one last thing that
      -- can get you. I learned the hard way that this command will NOT
      -- work successfully renaming a file from one filesystem to another,
      -- at least when those filesystems are NFS mounted. That is all.
      --

      utl_file.frename(srcdir,i_source_file,tgtdir,i_target_file,TRUE);

   end move_os_file;

   Procedure blob_into_file (i_directory in varchar2, i_file_name in varchar2, i_blob in blob)
   is

      l_file            utl_file.file_type;
      l_buffer          raw(32767);
      l_amount          binary_integer := 32767;
      l_pos             integer := 1;
      i_blob_len        integer;

   Begin

      i_blob_len := dbms_lob.getlength(i_blob);
      l_pos:= 1;

      -- Open the destination file.
      l_file := utl_file.fopen(i_directory,i_file_name,'wb', 32767);

      -- Read chunks of the BLOB and write them to the file
      -- until complete.
      while l_pos < i_blob_len loop
         dbms_lob.read(i_blob, l_amount, l_pos, l_buffer);
         utl_file.put_raw(l_file, l_buffer, TRUE);
         l_pos := l_pos + l_amount;
      end loop;

      -- Close the file.
      utl_file.fclose(l_file);

   End blob_into_file;

   Procedure file_into_blob(i_directory in varchar2, i_file_name in varchar2, o_blob out blob) 
   is
      src_loc       bfile   := bfilename(i_directory, i_file_name);
   Begin

      -- Initialize the dest blob
      o_blob := empty_blob();

      -- Open source binary file from OS
      dbms_lob.open(src_loc, dbms_lob.lob_readonly);

      -- Create temporary LOB object
      dbms_lob.createtemporary(
            lob_loc => o_blob
          , cache   => true
          , dur     => dbms_lob.session
      );

      -- Open temporary lob
      dbms_lob.open(o_blob, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);

      -- Load binary file into temporary LOB
      dbms_lob.loadfromfile(
            dest_lob => o_blob
          , src_lob  => src_loc
          , amount   => dbms_lob.getLength(src_loc));

      -- Close lob objects
      dbms_lob.close(o_blob);
      dbms_lob.close(src_loc);

   End file_into_blob;

   Function basename (i_filename in varchar2) return varchar2
   is
      v_basename        varchar2(1024);
   Begin

      --
      -- If the regex's below don't match, then it's already at its base name
      -- Return what was passed.
      --
      v_basename := i_filename;

      if regexp_like(i_filename,'^.*\\') then
         dbms_output.put_line('This is a Windows file');
         v_basename := regexp_substr(i_filename,'[^\]*$');
         dbms_output.put_line('Basename is : '||v_basename);
      end if;
      if regexp_like(i_filename,'^/') then
         dbms_output.put_line('This is a UNIX file');
         v_basename := regexp_substr(i_filename,'[^/]*$');
         dbms_output.put_line('Basename is : '||v_basename);
      end if;

      return v_basename;

   End basename;

   Function file_exists (i_directory in varchar2, i_filename in varchar2) return boolean
   is
      v_exists          boolean;
      v_file_length     number;
      v_block_size      number;
   Begin
      utl_file.fgetattr(upper(i_directory), i_filename, v_exists, v_file_length, v_block_size);   
      if (v_exists) then
         dbms_output.put_line('File '||i_filename||' exists, '||v_file_length||' bytes');
      else
         dbms_output.put_line('File '||i_filename||' does not exist');
      end if;

      return v_exists;

   end file_exists;

   Procedure convert_clob_to_blob (i_clob in clob, o_blob out blob)
   is

      v_in      pls_Integer := 1;
      v_out     pls_Integer := 1;
      v_lang    pls_Integer := 0;
      v_warning pls_Integer := 0;

   Begin

      dbms_lob.createtemporary(o_blob,TRUE);
      dbms_lob.converttoblob(o_blob,i_clob,DBMS_lob.getlength(i_clob),v_in,v_out,dbms_lob.default_csid,v_lang,v_warning);

   End convert_clob_to_blob;

   Procedure convert_blob_to_clob (i_blob in blob, o_clob out clob)
   is

      v_in      pls_Integer := 1;
      v_out     pls_Integer := 1;
      v_lang    pls_Integer := 0;
      v_warning pls_Integer := 0;

   Begin

      dbms_lob.createtemporary(o_clob,TRUE);
      dbms_lob.converttoclob(o_clob,i_blob,DBMS_lob.getlength(i_blob),v_in,v_out,dbms_lob.default_csid,v_lang,v_warning);

   End convert_blob_to_clob;

   Procedure blob_to_base64_string (i_blob in blob, o_clob out clob)
   is

      v_out_cl     clob;
      file_len     pls_integer;
      modulo       pls_integer;
      pieces       pls_integer;
      amt          binary_integer      := 23808;
      buf          raw (32767);
      buf_tx       varchar2(32767);
      pos          pls_integer         := 1;
      filepos      pls_integer         := 1;
      counter      pls_integer         := 1;
   Begin
      dbms_lob.createtemporary (v_out_cl, true, dbms_lob.call);
      file_len := dbms_lob.getlength (i_blob);
      modulo := mod (file_len, amt);
      pieces := trunc (file_len / amt);

      while (counter <= pieces) loop
         dbms_lob.read (i_blob, amt, filepos, buf);
         buf_tx:=utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 (utl_encode.base64_encode (buf));
         dbms_lob.writeappend (v_out_cl,length(buf_tx),buf_tx);
         filepos := counter * amt + 1;
         counter := counter + 1;
      end loop;

      if (modulo <> 0) THEN
         dbms_lob.read (i_blob, modulo, filepos, buf);
         buf_tx:=utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 (utl_encode.base64_encode (buf));
         dbms_lob.writeappend (v_out_cl,length(buf_tx),buf_tx);
      end if;

      o_clob := v_out_cl;

   End blob_to_base64_string;

   Function blob_to_base64_string (i_blob in blob) return clob
   is
      v_out_cl     clob;
      file_len     pls_integer;
      modulo       pls_integer;
      pieces       pls_integer;
      amt          binary_integer      := 23808;
      buf          raw (32767);
      buf_tx       varchar2(32767);
      pos          pls_integer         := 1;
      filepos      pls_integer         := 1;
      counter      pls_integer         := 1;
   Begin

      dbms_lob.createtemporary (v_out_cl, true, dbms_lob.call);
      file_len := dbms_lob.getlength (i_blob);
      modulo := mod (file_len, amt);
      pieces := trunc (file_len / amt);

      while (counter <= pieces) loop
         dbms_lob.read (i_blob, amt, filepos, buf);
         buf_tx:=utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 (utl_encode.base64_encode (buf));
         dbms_lob.writeappend (v_out_cl,length(buf_tx),buf_tx);
         filepos := counter * amt + 1;
         counter := counter + 1;
      end loop;

      if (modulo <> 0) THEN
         dbms_lob.read (i_blob, modulo, filepos, buf);
         buf_tx:=utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 (utl_encode.base64_encode (buf));
         dbms_lob.writeappend (v_out_cl,length(buf_tx),buf_tx);
      end if;

      return v_out_cl;

   End blob_to_base64_string;

   Procedure base64_string_to_blob (i_clob in clob, o_blob out blob)
   is

      v_out_bl blob;
      clob_size number;
      pos number;
      charBuff varchar2(32767);
      dBuffer RAW(32767);
      v_readSize_nr number;
      v_line_nr number;

   begin
      dbms_lob.createTemporary (v_out_bl, true, dbms_lob.call);
      v_line_nr:=greatest(65, instr(i_clob,chr(10)), instr(i_clob,chr(13)));
      v_readSize_nr:= floor(32767/v_line_nr)*v_line_nr;
      clob_size := dbms_lob.getLength(i_clob);
      pos := 1;

      while (pos < clob_size) loop
         dbms_lob.read (i_clob, v_readSize_nr, pos, charBuff);
         dBuffer := UTL_ENCODE.base64_decode (utl_raw.cast_to_raw(charBuff));
         dbms_lob.writeAppend (v_out_bl,utl_raw.length(dBuffer),dBuffer);
         pos := pos + v_readSize_nr;
      end loop;

      o_blob := v_out_bl;

   end base64_string_to_blob;

   Function  base64_string_to_blob (i_clob in clob) return blob
   is

      v_out_bl blob;
      clob_size number;
      pos number;
      charBuff varchar2(32767);
      dBuffer RAW(32767);
      v_readSize_nr number;
      v_line_nr number;

   begin
      dbms_lob.createTemporary (v_out_bl, true, dbms_lob.call);
      v_line_nr:=greatest(65, instr(i_clob,chr(10)), instr(i_clob,chr(13)));
      v_readSize_nr:= floor(32767/v_line_nr)*v_line_nr;
      clob_size := dbms_lob.getLength(i_clob);
      pos := 1;

      while (pos < clob_size) loop
         dbms_lob.read (i_clob, v_readSize_nr, pos, charBuff);
         dBuffer := UTL_ENCODE.base64_decode (utl_raw.cast_to_raw(charBuff));
         dbms_lob.writeAppend (v_out_bl,utl_raw.length(dBuffer),dBuffer);
         pos := pos + v_readSize_nr;
      end loop;

      return v_out_bl;

   end base64_string_to_blob;

end fileutils;
/

Show error;
```