# extract BLOB from Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I would like to export data from my database locally, the column that contains the blob is `"bbl_fic"`.

Is it possible to export my data without creating a package? With just one `SQL` request?

I can't use `C#` or `Java` to extract the data, and I don't really know how to do it.

thx!

Comment: I think in TOAD you can simply use the right-hand mouse button on data-grid and store the file locally.

Comment: i need to make a script for export all my data. The language I use just allows me to make loops and execute request SQL.

Comment: You may refer my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531576/oracle-export-a-table-with-blobs-to-an-sql-file-that-can-be-imported-again?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create a directory](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5007.htm#SQLRF01207) the database can use to export the data:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY export_dir AS '/path/to/your/directory';
```

Then use a PL/SQL script to export all the `BLOB`s to that directory:

```
DECLARE
  v_start          NUMBER(38,0);
  v_size  CONSTANT NUMBER( 5,0) := 32000;
  v_len            NUMBER(38,0);
  v_buffer         RAW(32000);
  v_file           UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN ( SELECT filename, bbl_fic FROM your_table )
  LOOP
    v_file  := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('EXPORT_DIR', r.filename, 'wb', 32760 );
    v_start := 1;
    v_len   := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH( r.bbl_fic );
    WHILE v_start <= v_len LOOP
      DBMS_LOB.READ(
        r.bbl_fic,
        LEAST( v_len - v_start + 1, v_size ),
        v_start,
        v_buffer
      );

      UTL_FILE.PUT_RAW( v_file, v_buffer );
      UTL_FILE.FFLUSH( v_file ); 
      v_start := v_start + v_size;
    END LOOP;
    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE( v_file );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: @Y.op My mistake - I forgot to add in the line to reset the start position when I copied it from a procedure to output a single blob (that did not need that reset).

Comment: it's working fine. but on 900 files, I have 60 files that are not exported, with the error message "file write error". You already had the same error ? (i copy them in the same folder, one file weight 538Ko, the name is correct)

Comment: What if I only have read access to the database and don't have permission to create the directory? Would I not be able to do this to my local? BTW, I'm using Oracle 12c on Windows.

Comment: @Julaayi You cannot create a directory on your local computer; it is a directory on the server. However, you can use other tools to get the BLOB such as through SQL Developer (or other IDEs) or accessing the database with a programming language such as Java/C#/etc.

Comment: @MT0 Unfortunately, I don't have experience with the programming languages and I did try the SQL Developer option earlier but with more than 50 tables, it's really hard for me to extract each object using SQL Developer. That's why looking for a viable solution through SQL at least. I don't know why I can't run a code that writes to my local when I am able to do the same with SQL Developer.

Comment: @Julaayi You can't create the directories locally using SQL because the SQL doesn't run locally; you send the query to the server and run it on the server and then if your SQL statement generates results then the results get sent back to your local machine to be displayed. The code above is a PL/SQL block and would be entirely run on the server.

Comment: @MT0 So, does that mean I would never be able to run this without running it on the server since PL/SQL is a Server Side Language?

Comment: @Julaayi SQL is a server-side language and will **ALWAYS** be run on the server; same for PL/SQL. If you want to run something locally then you will either need an IDE (i.e. SQL Developer, TOAD, SQL/Plus) to handle the results from an SQL query or you will need a programming language that runs locally and can send the queries to the server to get the BLOB files and process them.

Comment: @MT0 thanks for clarifying that. That's what I've been seeing every where but never got confirmation from anyone. Another question here - can I have the DBA create a directory as the shared network drive and then me running the code to extract the blobs?

Answer (score 5):

One choice is to use SQLcl ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html)

This tool is written in java and can use things like the nashorn/javascript engine for local scripting.  This snippet will perform a select of 3 columns.  ID just the table PK , name the name of the file to create, and content the BLOB to extract from the db.

The script command triggers this scripting. I placed this code below into a file named blob2file.sql

All this adds up to zero plsql, zero directories instead just some sql scripts with javascript mixed in.

```
script
// issue the sql
var binds = {}
var  ret = util.executeReturnList('select id,name,content from images',binds);

// loop the results
for (i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
   // debug is nice
    ctx.write( ret[i].ID  + "\t" + ret[i].NAME+ "\n");
   // get the blob stream

     var blobStream =  ret[i].CONTENT.getBinaryStream(1);

   // get the path/file handle to write to
     var path = java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(ret[i].NAME);

   // dump the file stream to the file
     java.nio.file.Files.copy(blobStream,path);
}
/
```

The result is my table emptied into files ( I only had 1 row )

```
SQL>  @blob2file.sql
1   eclipse.png
blob2file.sql   eclipse.png

SQL>
```